# remove my website access to IE and redirect to Edge

Tags: internet-explorer

I was looking to fix my website display bugs on IE.
As a result on the apple website, from internet explorer, we are directly redirected to Microsoft Edge, and I would like to know how to apply it to my own website.
Anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft [maintain a list of websites](https://edge.microsoft.com/neededge/v1) which should be redirected from IE to Edge. It isn't something you can configure yourself.

Consider using some kind of client-side detection (ideally feature detection for something you depend) and display an "Unsupported Browser" message with links to some suggested browsers instead.